# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 doesn't work when testing a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, testing, android-activity

I have an Android test project in which I test my main application. The tests for my provider work correctly. However, the tests that extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` fail with `NoClassDefFoundError`. The tests are very basic but it seems they fail in the constructor because they can't find the activity (although the package where it looks is OK).

I have similar test projects for other apps that work flawlessly. The only difference I see is that in this particular project I use android-support-v4.jar and I think this is where the problem lies. However, I haven't managed to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post, that was updated to include `android-support-v4.jar` case, will help you:
http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html